# Hide the file name (or show a default generic filename), especially if link_to image_tag image is broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I do not want the original filename showing in a link_to image_tag, especially if the image is broken.

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@event.poster.url(:profile), class: 'media-object'), @event.poster.url, target: '_blank' %>
```

Currently, if the image is broken it shows the filename beside it.   I would prefer: 'Event Poster'.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to have a default image saved for cases like this (assume it's stored in assets/images.default.png):

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :poster

  def poster
    return super if poster
    'default.png'
  end
end
```

This will return the poster's URL if it has one, and if not will return the default image.